# How to use and create Dynamic Panel in Dynamic Form Module in DNN?

Tags: drop-down-menu, dotnetnuke-5

I have some controls RadioButton,CheckBoxGroup and TextBoxes.I want to add these controls in this Dynamic Panel . And I have a Combo Box which have values 1,2,3,4,5,6. So when i select 1 from Combobox, 1 panel should display , when i select 2 from Combo box , 2 same panels should display an so on. Please help me anybody.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the Dynamic Forms module by DataSprings, you can create the intended behaviour by using "Question Events".  You would first go into each "panel" you want to hide and click the "Hide question until forced visible by question event" checkbox.  Then, go to the Question Events page and set up one event for each combobox value, with each one set to display the appropriate "panel".   Several demonstrations are available [here](http://www.datasprings.com/products/dnn-modules/dynamic-forms/dynamic-forms-demonstration-9).